# Why i getting subquery error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have here my script. This is my query that i used paint for showing my error:

[image]

the output should i want is to select the Weekday name = 'Saturday' from the table of schedules left join to the timesheet so

Example the date today is 7/29/2017 then = Saturday

```
SELECT effectiveDate,

CASE

  WHEN (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(effectiveDate, '%W') = 'Saturday'

  FROM schedules LEFT JOIN timesheet ON schedules.empid = timesheet.empid
  AND timesheet.date = schedules.effectiveDate  GROUP BY effectiveDate)

  THEN 'Saturday'

END

FROM schedules
LEFT JOIN timesheet ON schedules.empid = timesheet.empid AND timesheet.date = schedules.effectiveDate


WHERE effectiveDate <= CURDATE()
AND YEAR(effectiveDate) = YEAR(CURDATE())
AND MONTH(effectiveDate) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND schedules.empid = '40'
GROUP BY effectiveDate
```

Comment: What you want to display if it's not a saturday??

Comment: @JibinBalachandran  sir example that day is saturday so the user will log in at 8:00 AM in the morning. how can i replace that saturday to time when he or she login

Comment: *how can i replace that saturday to time when he or she login* means?? You want to display the time? Store the time somewhere?? What you want to do?

Comment: the remedy is the script said if (7/29/2017) is Saturday then the output will Saturday right? now the problem if the user will online on (7/29/2017) he/she login at 8:00 Am how can i replace the Saturday output to 8:00 AM

Comment: From where do you get the login time? Is effectiveDate  the login time??

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the subquery (which is the same as your main query), just refer to the column directly.

Also, you can use the `DAYNAME` function to get the name of the day, rather than `DATE_FORMAT`.

```
SELECT effectiveDate,
       CASE
            WHEN DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Saturday'
            THEN 'Saturday'
       END AS day
FROM schedules
LEFT JOIN timesheet ON schedules.empid = timesheet.empid AND timesheet.date = schedules.effectiveDate
WHERE effectiveDate <= CURDATE()
AND YEAR(effectiveDate) = YEAR(CURDATE())
AND MONTH(effectiveDate) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND schedules.empid = '40'
GROUP BY effectiveDate
```

Comment: Thanks alot guys.. the script is okay now :)

Comment: @Jibin and Barmar sir example that day is saturday so the user will log in at 8:00 AM in the morning. how can i replace that saturday to time when he or she login

Comment: `DAYNAME(NOW())` ?

Comment: no sir. Example the script said if Saturday then it will output Saturday right. now the problem is the user will be login at 8:00 AM on the day(Saturday) is it possible that Saturday output will replace when she/he login

Comment: Where do you get the time that she logs in? Just use the `DAYNAME()` function with that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery. You can directly access effectiveDate in your select query and do the same.

```
SELECT effectiveDate,
CASE
  WHEN DATE_FORMAT(effectiveDate, '%W')  = 'Saturday'
  THEN 'Saturday'
  ELSE 'Something else'
END AS day
FROM schedules
LEFT JOIN timesheet ON schedules.empid = timesheet.empid AND timesheet.date = schedules.effectiveDate
WHERE effectiveDate <= CURDATE()
AND YEAR(effectiveDate) = YEAR(CURDATE())
AND MONTH(effectiveDate) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND schedules.empid = '40'
GROUP BY effectiveDate
```

Comment: Thanks alot guys.. the script is okay now :)

Comment: sir example that day is saturday so the user will log in at 8:00 AM in the morning. how can i replace that saturday to time when he or she login